# clicking subscribe on mailchimp embedded code constantly gives undefined error

Tags: javascript, html, mailchimp

I've been having an awful awful time all day trying to get mailchimp in my website.

I have literally copied and pasted the embedded code from the mailchimp website and when I click the subscribe button i'm treated to:

> 404 Not Found
>
> The requested document was not found on this server. Web Server at
>   class.travel

I have literally NO idea what is going on.  And can't find anything on Google to boot.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction as to why this is happening?

Here's the form I'm using at my website http://class.travel  Again, this is just copied and pasted from mailchimp.  Is there some sort of API Key or JS files I need to include and it's just not stated on their website????

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//class.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=820adca0d3bcdd8bb18d6c2a9&amp;id=9768ebd530" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name </label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_820adca0d3bcdd8bb18d6c2a9_9768ebd530" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Also, P.S.  Web Noob, reporting in.

Comment: So: do you actually have a mailchimp login and a list to which you are subscribing people, and if so - are you using your actual mailchimp  userid and list id in your form? (in the params at the end of the action url)?

Comment: I have no idea why, but puttin it in an iframe seems to have worked... :|  Have no idea what's going on!  I appreciate the help Taryn.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Future on-lookers.  I never figured it out.

But putting it in an iframe made it work, for some godly unknown reason.